# How can I use SwingWorker safely?

Tags: java, swing, process, swingworker

I have just started to use `SwingWorker` for an iterative algorithm. After creating object of a class extended from SwingWorker, I performed the execute() function in the contructor function of my main class extended from JFrame. I use doInBackground() and process() functions during application runs. I don't need to stop the execution throughout the application. When user closes my JFrame application, do I need to carry out any stopping or cleaning task for SwingWorker? I mean, is it safe to close directly the JFrame application which uses SwingWorker?

Thanks

Comment: `SwingWorker` uses it's own `ExecutorService`, which backed by it's own `ThreadFactory` which generates daemon `Thread`s, meaning that the JVM will be able to exit once all the non-daemon thread's have finished. Is it safe?  That would come down to what it is your `SwingWorker` is actually doing, but if you're not holding any resources open or have other processes reliant on the result of the `SwingWorker` in order to completely their jobs (and close resources, etc), it should be

Comment: Thank you! It is the answer which I am looking for. Why didn't you write it as an answer instead of comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SwingWorker` uses it's own `ExecutorService`, which backed by it's own `ThreadFactory` which generates daemon `Thread`s, meaning that the JVM will be able to exit once all the non-daemon thread's have finished.

Is it safe? That would come down to what it is your `SwingWorker` is actually doing, but if you're not holding any resources open or have other processes reliant on the result of the `SwingWorker` in order to completely their jobs (and close resources, etc), it should be